# Using Ruby variable in Rsolr requests

Tags: ruby, rsolr

Is it possible to send a request to Solr using a Ruby variable?

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rsolr'

solr = RSolr.connect :url => 'http://solrserver.com'
response = rsolr.get 'select', :params => {:q => "prefName:#{params[:query]}"}
```

This code will generate a Bad Request error because the Ruby variable is ignored

```
RSolr::Error::Http - 400 Bad Request
Error: 'org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Cannot parse \'prefName:\': Encountered "<EOF>" at line 1, column 9.
```

Comment: Can you output the value of params[:query] and show us what it is?

Comment: params[:query] can be one character or a string, but the problem is with the Ruby variable, otherwise the request will work, for example :q => "prefName:smith"

Comment: And you've verified that in this case it is correct?

Comment: sorry I checked again, there was a problem in my code, the request works with Ruby variable